# How to automate ethtool?

Tags: command-line, networking

I tried Lubuntu on my desktop beside Windows XP. I really love it except for the following problem: I have a LAN broadband internet connection which flawlessly works in XP, but not in Lubuntu.

Each time I start Lubuntu, I have to run `sudo ethtool -s eth0 speed 10 duplex half autoneg off`. Then the wired connection is established.

Is there any method to save and automate this command so the Internet connection should establish automatically when I re-start Lubuntu?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can put this line in the file `/etc/rc.local`, before the `exit 0` (which needs to be the last one). You need to do this as administrator, eg with the command `sudo gedit /etc/rc.local`.

Comment: Your answer applies to pre-SystemD installations. (It may still work for newer systems, but your solution may become obsolete later on.) Therefore the better solution is to use `/etc/network/interface` as explained in @jfg956's answer.

Answer (score 6):

I do not know lubuntu, but it is based on ubuntu, which is based on debian, so a debian solution should work.

In debian, the network configuration goes in the `/etc/network/interface` file.  A command can be executed after an interface has been brought up using the `post-up` parameter.  So editing the `/etc/network/interface` file as below should be ok:

```
iface eth0 inet dhcp
    post-up /sbin/ethtool -s $IFACE speed 10 duplex half autoneg off
```

It also seems that you can directly specify `ethtool` option in the `/etc/network/interface` file:

```
iface eth0 inet dhcp
    link-speed 10
    link-duplex half
    ethernet-autoneg off
```

Those solutions would be better than using the `/etc/rc.local` trick as they keep all network configuration in a single and standard place.