# Ethernet not working on Ubuntu - Driver r8169: link down

Tags: 14.04, networking, dual-boot, drivers, ethernet

This is the first time that I am using Ubuntu 14.04 alongside Windows 10 on my Lenovo Z51. My Ethernet connection is not recognized in Ubuntu, but it is connected in Windows. Wireless is working fine.

```
chirag@chirag:~$ lspci -knn | grep Eth -A2; ifconfig
02:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 15)
Subsystem: Lenovo Device [17aa:3826]
Kernel driver in use: r8169
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr f0:76:1c:b9:ef:d6  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:212 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:212 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1 
          RX bytes:19539 (19.5 KB)  TX bytes:19539 (19.5 KB)

wlan1     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr ac:e0:10:2e:b1:b7  
          inet addr:10.42.0.18  Bcast:10.42.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::aee0:10ff:fe2e:b1b7/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:1179 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:1206 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:838341 (838.3 KB)  TX bytes:183256 (183.2 KB)

chirag@chirag:~$ cat /etc/network/interfaces
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

I tried adding `auto eth0` and `iface eth0 inet dhcp` in `/etc/network/interfaces` using

```
sudo su
gedit /etc/netwwork/interfaces
```

but after this, it took very long to restart with a message on the startup screen:

*Waiting for Network Configuration*

and then:

*Starting without full Network Configuration*

As a result, I removed `auto eth0` and `iface eth0 inet dhcp` from `/etc/network/interfaces`

After rebooting with the wireless switched off and the ethernet cable attached:

```
chirag@chirag:~$ dmesg | grep -e eth -e r8169
[    0.965727] r8169 Gigabit Ethernet driver 2.3LK-NAPI loaded
[    0.965739] r8169 0000:02:00.0: can't disable ASPM; OS doesn't have    ASPM control
[    0.975229] r8169 0000:02:00.0 eth0: RTL8168h/8111h at     0xffffc90000cbe000, f0:76:1c:b9:ef:d6, XID 14100880 IRQ 48
[    0.975232] r8169 0000:02:00.0 eth0: jumbo features [frames: 9200     bytes, tx checksumming: ko]
[    4.311764] vga_switcheroo: detected switching method   \_SB_.PCI0.GFX0.ATPX handle
[    6.616934] r8169 0000:02:00.0 eth0: link down
[    6.616935] r8169 0000:02:00.0 eth0: link down
[    6.617017] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready

chirag@chirag:~$ ethtool eth0
Settings for eth0:
Supported ports: [ TP MII ]
Supported link modes:   10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full 
                        100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full 
                        1000baseT/Half 1000baseT/Full 
Supported pause frame use: No
Supports auto-negotiation: Yes
Advertised link modes:  10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full 
                        100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full 
                        1000baseT/Full 
Advertised pause frame use: Symmetric Receive-only
Advertised auto-negotiation: Yes
Speed: 10Mb/s
Duplex: Half
Port: MII
PHYAD: 0
Transceiver: internal
Auto-negotiation: on
Cannot get wake-on-lan settings: Operation not permitted
Current message level: 0x00000033 (51)
               drv probe ifdown ifup
Link detected: no
```

Link to my network diagnostics result:

http://paste.ubuntu.com/15960787/

Comment: You posted the *wireless-info* for an ethernet problem. Most of it is unrelated. Please reboot with the wireless switched off and the ethernet cable attached, and run: `dmesg | grep -e eth -e r8169` and edit your question to add the result.

Comment: @chili555 I have added the result  of `dmesg | grep -e eth -e r8169` to my question.

Comment: @Chirag How did you get the "network diagnostic" output you have linked?

Answer (score 8):

The driver *r8169*  is problematic and there are several things we might try. Let's start with the simplest first and see if we can fix it. If not, I will edit this answer to proceed to the more complex.

Please open a terminal and do:

```
sudo ethtool -s eth0 speed 100 duplex full autoneg off
```

Now check:

```
dmesg | grep eth0
```

Does the link come back up? Note that it was previously:

> r8169 0000:02:00.0 eth0: link down

I notice that you are dual-booting with Windows. This is an issue with the driver *r8169* in some cases. Please see: https://en.opensuse.org/SDB:Realtek_8169_driver_problem In particular:

> 2. You enable "Wake-on-lan after shutdown." in the Windows device manager. This prevents the Windows driver to disable the card. With
>      newer Windows driver versions this option is not available anymore,
>      instead there is an option "Shutdown Wake On Lan". Changing that new
>      option from "Enabled" to "Disabled" cannot be confirmed to fix the
>      issue.

Please find and reverse the setting for Wake-on-LAN in Windows. Reboot into Ubuntu and check again:

```
dmesg | grep -e r8169 -e eth0
```

Any improvement?

If you have compiled the *r8168* driver, I suggest you blacklist r8169:

```
sudo -i
echo "blacklist r8169"  >>  /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
exit
```

Reboot. Confirm that *r8168* is loaded:

```
lsmod
```

Any improvement?

Comment: The link is still down. Also, I have added the result of `ethtool eth0` to my question.

Comment: Please see my edit above.

Comment: Disabled *Shutdown Wake On LAN*  but didn't see any improvement. Tried to intall r8168 driver after downloading it from Realtek website, and it gave the error:  `Could not remove module r8169: Operation not permitted`

Comment: Please see my edit above in a few moments.

Comment: In order to make `sudo ethtool -s eth0 speed 100 duplex full autoneg off` permanent  try http://askubuntu.com/questions/268200/how-to-automate-ethtool/268321