# Fresh Install over Windows. Internet Connection completely broken

Tags: 16.04, network-manager, internet, ethernet, connection

I installed 16.04 over Windows today and everything is broken! My ethernet cable is my sole connection to the internet and it's just not working at all. It's a Realtek device with the default driver r8169. The thing is plugged in and it's detected by Ubuntu but my router doesn't see it at all. I've tried turning off the DHCP and set it static. I've tried restarting the network manager. I swapped the drivers to r8168 and that has just made things worse.

Any help would be appreciated! It's midnight here but I will respond back first thing in the morning! Thanks!

Comment: Identify your wireless card.

Comment: sudo lshw -C network tells me RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express gigabit ethernet controlller

Comment: Did ypu see this? https://askubuntu.com/questions/761027/ethernet-not-working-on-ubuntu-driver-r8169-link-down

Comment: That looks like your ethernet, what about your wireless ? Google search "ubuntu RTL8111/8168/8411" there are several questions here and on the web. I am not sure which one will work best . Example - https://unixblogger.com/2016/08/11/how-to-get-your-realtek-rtl8111rtl8168-working-updated-guide/

Comment: For the unixblogger site, I tried doing that but the lack of an internet connection makes it just short of impossible to do

Comment: for the other askubuntu, It's similar but under the ethernet port it also says "Interrupt: 29 Base Address: 0xc000